# Ubuntu 12.04 crashes on startup for newer versions of Linux, possibly related to WiFi

Tags: 12.04, boot, wireless, realtek

My computer gets to the screen with the Ubuntu logo and the orange/white dots, and then the screen goes black, spits out a lot of error messages, and cannot boot. (If it'd be helpful, I can take a photo of my screen in this state.)

I've found I can successfully boot if my wireless card is turned off. As soon as I turn it on, my computer crashes with the same black screen of death. I can also successfully boot if I choose "Previous Linux Version" and select a few versions back (I think 3.0.6).

Here are some relevant details about my setup:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Computer: Lenovo x230
- Wireless: Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
- Processor: Intel Core i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- RAM: 16 GB of RAM

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is facing this problem: Upgrading to 14.04 fixed the problem entirely. I'm still not certain what the problem was!